# We had $m$ (odd number)....

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What we will get if we divide $2^{\varphi(m)-1}$ at $m$?
(The answer should be at $m$...)

Thank you!

(Mabye it's something that connect to Euler theorem or Fermat Small Theorem).

Comment: What precisely are you asking? Generally, $m$ doesn't divide $2^{\varphi(m)-1}$.

Comment: Yes, it sould be someting with $\pmod{m}$....

Comment: $\mod{n}$ or $\mod{m}$?

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: m, sorry :-) I used "n" just as simple to explain...

Comment: Are you asking for the REMAINDER?

Comment: @N.S. - Yes....

Comment: FYI, I've heard it as "Fermat's little theorem", rather than "Fermat's small theorem"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that

$$2^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$

Thus

$$2^{\phi(m)-1} \equiv 2^{-1} \pmod{m}$$

Now, 
$$2^{-1} \equiv 2^{-1} (m+1) \equiv \frac{m+1}{2} \pmod{n} $$

Where $\frac{m+1}{2} \pmod{m}$ makes sense since $m$ is odd.

Thus, the remainder is $\frac{m+1}{2}$.

Comment: But how it can be? $2^{-1}$ it not in $\mathbb{Z}$ ....

Comment: @YoavFridman Do you know what the inverse (or reciprocal) of an element is in modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, now I'm understand you!
But can you explain me the last line? ($2^{-1}\equiv 2^{-1}(m+1)...$)

Comment: @YoavFridman $1 \equiv m+1 \pmod{m}$. Then, as $m+1$ is even, you have $1 \equiv m+1 \equiv 2 \frac{m+1}{2} \pmod{m}$. Multiply this by the inverse of $2$.

Comment: Thank you!
BTW, at the last line do you mean $m$ insted of $n$?

Comment: @YoavFridman Yes, fixed that.

Comment: BTW. I'm not sure if you answer the question - the, I dont see here that you **divide** $2^{\varphi{(m)}-1}$ at $m$. I'm right? or I miss something?? Thank you!
If I'm understanig it right, $x\equiv...\pmod{m}$ means: what will be the remainder if we divide $x$ at $m$.

Comment: @YoavFridman If you divide $a$ to $m$, long division tells you that $a=qm+r$. But then $a \equiv r \pmod{m}$. Moreover, if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $0 \leq b <m$ it is easy to show that $b$ has to be $r$... Any problem of finding the remainder when divided by $m$ is a problem of $\pmod{m}$ arithmetic.